# Keep IIS 7 URL Rewrite module from matching /ScriptResource.axd

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have a website and I have installed URL Rewrite using Web Platform Installer. I wish to allow a user friendly URL like www.foo.com/123456 to go to www.foo.com/page.aspx?blah=123456.  Using the User-friendly URL template accomplishes this except that the created rule also matches all of the /scriptresource.axd?blahblah created by ASP.NET which of course breaks most functionality.  My initial attempts to exclude the script resource files have failed.

The regex generated by the tool is `^([^/]+)/?$`

Answer (score 7):

You can prevent this by adding the following to the  section of your rule:

```
<add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of the things you're interested in matching end with .com, 
.com\?\d{6,7}$  should match a period followed by com followed by a question mark followed by either 6 or 7 digits, provided they occur at the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem as well. I found that is was my outbound url rewrite rule blocking the script resources. I managed to get round the problem by adding a precondition to my outbound rule that excluded files containing axd